# How do i move an entirety of a collection to specific cordinates?

Tags: transforms, collections

There's a rather large collection that i need to have an entirety of it moved to a very specific cordinate. I really couldn't find a way to move an collection in a manner like that. Any way i can do that?

Comment: Please specify.. each element to its own coordinate? All to the same? Collection to coordinate, preserving relative offset? .. and, how do you want to enter the coordinate (what interface would you like) ?

Comment: Preserving the general shape of the collection so it looks the same while moving the entire thing to a specific cordinates. I'm not sure which interface i want to use because i'm still pretty new to using blender but my requirements are that i should be able to put in specific X Y Z cordinates myself and for it to be not overly complicated and simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. select one object of collection
2. shift-g -> collection

now all objects of collection are selected

press n to open side panel

hold alt (or ctrl) key while changing coordinates

[image]